# Encode the text in the form... Any solution?

Tags: javascript, urlencode, space

I do have a very simple HTML form that would take the value of the textbox and create a URL. 
Here is my form:

```
    <form id="searchForm" method="GET" action="http://searchserver/results.aspx target="_blank">
            <input type="text" name="p" size="18" maxlength="256" value="hello world"/>
</form>
```

As you can see, when hitting enter, it sends the value to the new browser with the url as: "http://searchserver/results.aspx?p=hello+world"

Is there a way to force the plus (+) sign here into the %20 character?  So it would be: "http://searchserver/results.aspx?p=hello**%20**world"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd do it without any framework:

```
var form = document.getElementById('searchForm');
var el = form.elements[0];

document.location = form.action + "?" + el.name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(el.value);
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Johannes,  Thanks for the quick reply.  To be honest with you, I can't think of how to integrate this into my form.  Would you kindly escalate this a bit more?  How to add this in a javascript function? and how to call it out before sending to the new brower?

Comment: You might have some catching up to do :) I recommend this book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/

But this is the above code in context: http://jsfiddle.net/jfahrenkrug/qBmFd/3/